# How to navigate folders in HTML/Atom

Tags: html, css, favicon

I want to upload a favicon for my HTML/CSS website, I used:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

But it doesn't work. Here are my project folders:

```
Ghazi Aldeeb
    Resources
        Images
            favicon.ico
    Scripts
        CSS
            stylesheet.css
        HTML
            index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="../Images/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify all the directory. In your case (if the html file is into the folder "Ghazi Aldeeb"),

```
<link rel="icon" href="/Ghazi Aldeeb/Resources/Images/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work